# DLLs referenced in a project used by another project in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

There are many similar questions but they don't seem to make too much sense of my specific problem.

I have a project A, a class library which references an external DLL

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, 
Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Project A compiles fine - I set the referenced DLL to copy local and left Alias untouched as global.

Project B references Project A and everything is just dandy, except at the end of the compilation, I get:

> ```
> Error 5215    The type
> ```
>
> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client,
>   Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. C:...\Content\Status.aspx.cs   9   13  ProjectB

Everything is in the same solution file. What am I missing in this case? The reference of Project A from Project B is done via Project reference.

I this the feared dll hell I keep hearing about?

Comment: Does project B use that DLL directly?

Comment: I think @Jon is on to something. You may have to explictly use it in Project A. I am willing to test it out though.

Comment: Does project B use the `WorkItem` class? Is it returned from a method in Project A?

Comment: Ah yes it does -- That's the problem, you're right! You should post it as a solution!

Comment: Matt, because there is more than one commenter here; so I am _not sure_ @John will saw your comment in his inbox, so I think you have to add `@John` implicitly. _maybe he will see it now after I added `@John` in this comment :)_

Comment: I've posted my original thought as an answer, glad I could help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does project B use the `WorkItem` class? Is it returned from a method in Project A?

If that's the case, then the DLL containing that class needs to be referenced by project B. How else could project B declare an object of that type, or call the methods of that class?

Answer (score -1):

Project B uses that DLL directly, so that project needs to reference the DLL as well.

Comment: I am not sure why this downvoted, the answer is a valid one, although not the correct one in this particular case.  If the DLL is used in some fashion, either directly or from a return value from a method call, it needs to be referenced.

Comment: Project B does not use the DLL directly, only indirectly, through project A.